# How to get $_POST working with my editable jquery table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this editable html table that I've got working, so you can click the cells and edit the text, however I can't get it to post the values as well.

I know there's a problem with the 5 lines of code under the comment on script.js

test.php

```
<h2><u>Edit</u></h2>
    <form action="ajax/name.php" name="edit_template_form" id="edit_template_form" method="post">
        <?php print "<table border=\"1\" class=\"editableTable\">
        <tr>
        <th>Template Name</th>
        <th>Template Description</th>
        </tr>";
            foreach($res as $row){ 
                $temp_description = $row['template_description'];
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td id=\"edit_name\" name=\"edit_name\">". $row['template_name']. "</td>";
            echo "<td id=\"edit_template\" name=\"edit_template\">". nl2br($temp_description). "</td>";
            echo "<tr/>"; 
            } 
        print "</table>"; ?>
    </form>
    <div id="template_edit"></div>
```

name.php

```
if (isset($_POST['edit_template'])) {
    $template_edit = $db->escape($_POST['edit_template']);

    $user = $db->escape($user);
    $db->update('templates', array('template_description' => $template_edit), 'AND userID="'.$user.'"');

    echo $_POST['edit_template'];
    }


if (isset($_POST['edit_name'])) {   
    $template_name = $db->escape($_POST['edit_name']);

    $user = $db->escape($user);
    $db->update('templates', array('template_name' => $template_name), 'AND userID="'.$user.'"');

    echo $_POST['edit_name'];
    }
```

script.js

```
$(function () {
    $("td").dblclick(function () {

        var OriginalContent = $(this).text();

        $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
        $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
        $(this).children().first().focus();

            $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {

                //POST values
                var edit_template = $('#edit_template').val();
                var edit_name = $('#edit_name').val();

                    $.post('ajax/name.php', {edit_name: edit_name, edit_template: edit_template}, function(data) {
                            $('div#template_edit').text(data);
                            });  

                    var newContent = $(this).val();

                  $(this).parent().text(newContent);
                  $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
                }
        });

    $(this).children().first().blur(function(){
        $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
        $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
    });
    });
});
```

Comment: is `ajax/name.php` receiving the correct data? To check, I would `var_dump($_POST);` in the php file and `console.log(data)` in your `success` callback in the `ajax` call

Comment: var_dump has returned 2 empty values, which makes sense... Why are the values on my td tags not pulling through?

Comment: Well you are getting the value of the input with `$('div#edit_name')`, but when you change the html to an input, you are not setting the ID as `edit_name`